# C++ istringstream in loop not changing its value

Tags: c++, loops, istringstream

I'm fairly new to c++ and have encountered a problem where by searching alone I couldn't find a solution.

The problem is, why does the istringstream never changes its value inside the loop below?

It takes the value from dirs[ 0 ] and dirs[ 1 ] and never changes them to the increasing int i.
Btw. the values in dirs[ i ] and dirs [ i + 1 ] are stored as hex values (e.g. 0F9C8924).

Below is my latest setup, i've tried several other ways but with no success, for example having istringstream inside the loop and with ios_base::trunc and whatsoever.

Also `dirs[ i ]` etc. DO have different values and are read correctly, but when trying to make the string hex into a unsigned int via istringstream it never takes the new values.

```cpp
unsigned int f;
unsigned int t;
istringstream ss;
istringstream ss2;
for( int i = 0; i < count; i+=3 ) {
    ss.clear();
    ss2.clear();
    ss.str( dirs[ i ] );
    ss2.str( dirs[ i + 1 ] );

    ss >> f;
    ss2 >> t;



    // do something else with dirs[ i + 3 ], not relevant
}
```

`count` and `dirs` are a global variable and `count` is increased in another function, its the count of values in `dirs`.

I am sorry if this has been asked before, but the solutions I found somehow didn't work for me.
Such as `ss.clear()` or `while( ss >> f )`

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Not enough clear. You should atleast tell us what values `dirs` contains, and what output do you expect? And what output this current program *actually* gives?

Comment: Streams don't have a "value". They are flows of data.

Comment: dirs values are always hex strings (for example 0F9C8924) and I want these hex strings to be converted into unsigned int. The outputs are [b]always[/b] the unsigned int of the first and second entry of dirs. Means its always dirs[0] and dirs[1].

Comment: I feel really stupid now, and would like to apologize to those who tried to help.

The problem was that there was a small error in the hex strings which were being saved into the `dirs` array. As a result istringstream couldn't convert the string to to an int. Sorry for wasting your time. =(

Answer (score 5):

The question is a bit confusing. Do you mean that the input is a string like "0F9C8924"?

If so, try `ss >> hex >> f;`.

You should write some error handling into your code so that you know when and why things are going wrong. `ss.clear()` just blindly clears error flags without ever finding out why they were set in the first place.

Comment: The inputs are always hex strings. And I want them to be unsigned int. I'll try to see if there are any error messages.

Comment: Alright it does show the errors, they are _eof_ and _fail_. The first run in the loop (i = 0) its just _eof_ afterwards it also adds the _failbit_. Now I just need to know why...

Comment: @zhade: If it's `eof`, then quite simply you ran out of input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unsigned int f;
unsigned int t;
for( int i = 0; i < count; i+=3 )
{
    istringstream ss1( dirs[ i ] );
    istringstream ss2( dirs[ i + 1 ] );

    ss1 >> f;
    ss2 >> t;

    // do something else with dirs[ i + 3 ], not relevant
}
```

I assume you thought clear() would empty the stream. And str(<string>) would set some text into the stream. Probably best to declare the stringstream inside the loop. This means they are destroyed at the end of the loop and re-created each time the loop is entered. Then you can just initialize them with there constructor.

Comment: I've tried this before, but with the same result. Now with the error detection its the same as before, after the first run the _failbit_ is set.

Answer (score 0):

This prints out the decimal values of the hex strings.  Is this what you want?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using std::istringstream;
unsigned int f;
unsigned int t;
const char * dirs[12] = { 
    "0x15", "0x16", "dummy", 
    "0x11", "0x12", "dummy",
    "0x115", "0x116", "dummy",
    "0x111", "0x112", "dummy"
    };
unsigned int count = sizeof(dirs) / sizeof(const char *);
int main(int, char **) {
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i+=3 )
    {
        istringstream ss1( dirs[ i ] );
        istringstream ss2( dirs[ i + 1 ] );

        ss1 >> std::hex >> f;
        ss2 >> std::hex >> t;
        std::cout << "f is " << f << std::endl;
        std::cout << "t is " << t << std::endl;

        // do something else with dirs[ i + 2 ], not relevant
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```